# getContent() is rendering the wrong page - why?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Am on a VF page called 'selectpages' and can click 'render to pdf' button. Button action is intended to simply render another VF page to an attachment as follows -

Attachment ax = new attachment(name = filenameToUse, parentid = quot.id);

```
    PageReference bl = Page.tc_report;
    bl.getParameters().put('q',qid);
    bl.setRedirect(true);
    Blob b = bl.getContent(); // this is returning blob from current page, not page tc_report...
    ax.Body = b;
    insert ax;
```

So why does the resulting attachment contain the 'selectpages' rendered nicely as a pdf and not the tc_report page?....

Hoping this is a quick one - has me puzzled, hoping for someone to clip me over the ear for some obvious thing I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this the solution was to create a different page controller class, so that view state was purged at page render.

Answer (score 0):

Use getContentAsPDF function

```
 Blob b = bl.getContentAsPDF ();
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback - same problem still occurs, as the page itself is by default rendering as pdf.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this the solution was to create a different page controller class, so that view state was purged at page render.